# S3 website's contents overlapping for multiple AngularJS sites

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

We have deployed several AngularJS websites on S3 quite a while. The sites are working usually well only after Cntrl + F5 from Google Chrome. Now the main problem we are facing that --

Displaying another different site’s contents to current one which is not expected in anyway.

Here, we have deployed qa.example.net as well as prod.example.net in S3. Both are calling completely different API respectively but still we can see many unexpected behaviours. Such as --

After login in qa.example.net, we can see the real data of prod.example.net.
After doing Cntrl+F5, initially it resolved. So,we thought it’s local cache issue but
Now a days even after doing this, issue still persist.
To get rid of this, we need to perform multiple times Cntrl+F5 from Chrome in Incognito mode.

**Bucket configurations**

- Enable Static Hosting → Yes.
- Index Document → index.html
- Error Document → 404.html
- Grantee → s3user

### S3 Bucket Policy conf for qa.example.net

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::qa.example.net/*"
    }
]}
```

### S3 Bucket Policy conf for prod.example.net

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod.example.net/*"
    }
]}
```

### S3 CORS conf for Both buckets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>1</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening for domain level buckets also ?
Do you see overlap between say example.com and example1.com ?